# Can the Fisher Information be Used to Evaluate the Quality of a Regression Model?

Tags: regression, estimation, maximum-likelihood, inference, fisher-information

**Can the Fisher Information be Used to Evaluate the Quality of a Regression Model?**

I have often heard of the Fisher Information described as "how much information about an unknown parameter we can get from a sample - how well we can measure a parameter, given a certain amount of data." In principle, this sounds like it can be used to relate some observed data (i.e. the sample) to the parameters of a regression model (i.e. unknown parameters).

For example, given some data and a regression model - the Fisher Information for each parameter (i.e. beta coefficient) can be calculated and placed into a matrix:

[image]

Based on this, I think it might be reasonable to interpret the Fisher Information as follows: Suppose you have some observed data and a linear regression model (e.g. 4 beta coefficients (beta_0, beta_1, beta_2, beta_3) estimated using a Normal Likelihood Function) - the Fisher Information could tell you the maximum amount of "information" your data can provide about each of these beta regression coefficients. If the Fisher Information for these parameters given your data happens to be very small - this could serve as a heuristic, and indicate that any such regression model created from this data is likely to perform poorly in the real world (e.g. perhaps if you collect more data, more information could be known about these regression parameters).

However, I never see the Fisher Information being calculated in regression diagnostic procedures within popular statistical computing software packages (e.g. R, SAS):

[image]

Regression Model Diagnostics often include confidence intervals on the parameter estimates, p-values, AIC/BIC of the regression model, MSE, R-squared value, Goodness of Fit, Maximum Likelihood of the Model - furthermore, OOB (Out of Bag) Error can be calculated using Cross Validation style procedures (e.g. K-Fold Cross Validation).

**But is there a reason that the Fisher Information Matrix for the model parameters is never displayed? Can the Fisher Information be used on statistical models created from real world data to assess the maximum amount of information we can get about the model parameters from an observed dataset?**

**References:**

- https://www.statisticshowto.com/fisher-information/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information

**Note: Visualization of the Fisher Information** (from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pneluWj-U-o)

[image]

Suppose we are given random samples from a (Univariate) Normal Distribution with an unknown mean and known variance, with the task of estimating the mean (the "parameter" of interest) : When the variance is large ("left"), the random samples do not carry a lot of information about the model parameter - all values of the mean are almost as likely, which is not ideal. When the variance is small ("right"), the random samples carry a lot more information about the model parameter - there are certain values of the mean that are far more likely than others (i.e. the center).

We can see an example of this with two model parameters below:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer your question at a sufficient level of detail, but you may find the [Cramer-Rao bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound) interesting in its relationship between uncertainty of a parameter in a model to the Fisher information matrix.

Comment: @ Galen: thank you for your reply! I will look into this